# communicate between fragments with missing id

Tags: android-fragments, message-passing

I have an activity and two fragments. The first fragment is inflated with the activity, now I need to send data from first fragment to second fragment, so I
 send data to the activity first - but how do I pass on the data to fragment two, when I cann´t say R.id.fragment_two - hence it is not present in the activity.xml.
Any help would be appreciated